# How to mock unit tests for Golang function calling an AWS Service multiple times with different methods?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go, aws-sdk-go

I have the following function that makes multiple calls to AWS IAM. I am able to run unit tests on single calls. However when I run a test on the one below I get a panic: **"runtime error, invalid memory or nil pointer dereference"**

```
  func (iamDependency *iamService) CreateMyUser(userName string) (string, error){

    //first IAM call
    err:=iamDependency.GetUser(&iam.GetUserInput{UserName: userName})

    if err != nil {

      fmt.Println("Failed to get user, attempting to create")
      
      //second IAM call
      err:=iamDependency.CreateUser(&iam.CreateUserInput{UserName: userName})
  
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create user\n", err )
      }
  }
}
```

Here is my mock and test:

```
type mockSomeOutput{}

type mockedIamCall{
  iamiface.IAMAPI
  Response mockSomeOutput
}

func TestCreateMyUser(t *testing.T){
  t.Run("Successful user create", fun(t *testing.T){
    mo:= mockOutput{}

    m:= mockedIamCall{Response: mo}
    
    d:= iamService{
      iamInstance: m,
    }

   mockedUser:="TestUser"
   
   _, err:= d.ResetCredentials(&mockedUser)
   
   if err != nil {
     t.Fatal("Everything should be ok")
   }
  })
}
```

I'm wondering whether there are any tricks or guidelines for making unit tests for this kind of function in Golang.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Raymond thanks for the response, it was insightful. However I seem to have found a simpler answer to my own question. I created my own interface

```
type UserCreator interface{
  GetUser(*iam.GetUserInput) (*iam.GetUserOutput, error)
  CreateUser(*iam.CreateUserInput) (*iam.CreateUserInput, error)
}


func CreateMyUser(iamSvc UserCreator, userName string) (string, error){

    //first IAM call
    _, err:=iamSvc.GetUser(&iam.GetUserInput{UserName: userName})

    if err != nil {

      fmt.Println("Failed to get user, attempting to create")
      
      //second IAM call
      _, err:=iamSvc.CreateUser(&iam.CreateUserInput{UserName: userName})
  
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create user\n", err )
      }
  }
}
```

And then for my test I just implement the interface, override these methods, and pass a mock:

```
type mockUserCreator{
  Response string
}

func (m * mockUserCreator) GetUser(input *iam.GetUserInput)(*iam.GetUserOutput, error){
return &iam.GetUserOutput{}, nil
}

func (m * mockUserCreator) CreateUser(input *iam.CreateUserInput)(*iam.CreateUserOutput, error){
return &iam.CreateUserOutput{}, nil
}

func TestCreateMyUser(t *testing.T){
  testcases:=[]struct{
   TestName string
  }{
    {
      TestName:"Some test"
    }
  }
  for _, tt := range testcases{
    t.Run(tt.TestName, func(t *testing.T){
      m := mockUserCreator{}

     mockUser := "TestUser"

      _, err:= CreateMyUser(&m, mockUser)
      
      if err != nil {
        t.Error("TestCreateMyUser returned and error: %s", err)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try using: https://github.com/golang/mock

You can creating mock implementation for the iamiface.IAMAPI (from the actual interface) then expecting the function calls and mocking the response.

Creating the mock implementation of the interface using `mockgen`.

```
mockgen -source={path to IAM API interface}
```

And then you can expect the function calls with something like this on the test cases:

```
function TestExample(t *testing.T) {
  ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
  mockIAMAPI := mock_package.NewMockIAMAPI(ctrl)
  mockIAMAPI.EXPECT().GetUser(expectedInput).Return(mockResponse).Times(1)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).